# How to install MySQL/Apache/PHP on Mac OS X?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, mamp

Do you guys recommend using MAMP, or should I go about a manual install? I am savvy enough to do the install manually (I have done many manual Apache installs with Ruby on Rails in the past), but I am not sure if MAMP is worth it.

Any guides, tips, or opinions are welcomed, as well!

**UPDATE**

This will be used for development purposes. Speed/Efficiency is not the most important thing. As long as php/apache/mysql are all available, I should be okay.

Keep in mind, MySQL has already been installed (using Homebrew), and I prefer to install mysql/postgresql that way.

Thanks!

Comment: For what purpose? Development, experimentation, production?

Comment: Good question, updating the original question now.

Comment: I recall MAMP being awkward if your account is not an admin account (or whatever the term is on a mac), though that may have just been the port number it was using. Apart from that it did the job fine.

Comment: I thought OSX just came with Apache/PHP preinstalled?

Comment: Can some one please update this answer for OSX 10.8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the instructions on [this page](http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/), works perfectly fine.

MAMP is good, but it's gonna install everything from scratch. The same goes for PHP via homebrew. I have tried all of those. But you have to remember that your Mac comes bundled with Apache and PHP out of the box. You just have to add MySQL to the mix and get rolling.

Comment: Good Resource. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mamp is easiest but without paying for pro, virtual hosts are difficult to manage.

I found the default version already on the system a pain to manage due to some osx specific config in apache's httpd.conf. But you can use mac ports or homebrew (my preferred) for a custom php/apache install.

My preferred and in my opinion the cleanest way is to install virtualbox and run a full LAMP stack. This is the most flexible and a lot closer to anything you may be hosting on. If you havent done any sysadmin before it is a pretty good way to learn a bit more

Comment: So are php/apache available formulae on homebrew? I wasn't aware of that, as it would definitely be my preferred method.

Comment: There are non-official formulae available http://notfornoone.com/2010/07/install-php53-homebrew-snow-leopard/

Comment: Managing Virtual hosts on OSX is a piece of cake with [VirtualHostX](http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/)